# How to solve error running pod install on Iphone 11 on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that there are many similar questions about this problem, I try them all but didn't work.
The problem started after trying to run the code on Xcode on a physical device.
The error is below whe I say on the command line "flutter run".

```
Running pod install...                                           1,234ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      - Flutter
      - flutter_secure_storage
      - local_auth
      - shared_preferences
      - vibration

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_secure_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_secure_storage/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `local_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/local_auth/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `vibration` from `.symlinks/plugins/vibration/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update

    Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
      A Flutter
      A flutter_secure_storage
      A local_auth
      A shared_preferences
      A vibration

    Downloading dependencies

    -> Installing Flutter (1.0.0)

    -> Installing flutter_secure_storage (3.3.1)

    -> Installing local_auth (0.0.1)

    -> Installing shared_preferences (0.0.1)

    -> Installing vibration (1.7.2)
      - Running pre install hooks
    [!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries:
    (/Users/ilkerimamoglu/Desktop/Flutter_MQTT-master 3 copy/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework)

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in
    verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:74:in `each_key'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:74:in `block in
    verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:73:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:73:in
    `verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:38:in `validate!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:595:in `validate_targets'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Even I didn't do something else, it gives me this error. I tried to delete `Flutter.framework` and run `pod install` but it is giving me `` [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory. ``
What can I do?

Comment: Try to delete ```Podfile.lock``` (be sure, Podfile.lock not Podfile)

Comment: O Yes, I am sorry I meant Podfile.lock

Comment: I did it but still it is not working

Comment: Did you try deleting ```Pods``` folder and run it again?

Comment: I delete it, and then it adds it while running, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

I met the same situation. And this is the solution I found.
https://armen-mkrtchian.medium.com/run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-and-macos-big-sur-developer-transition-kit-b62acffc1387

Basically:

- Locate Terminal.app in Finder. (Applications->Terminal.app)
- Right-click and choose Get Info
- Check the “Open using Rosetta”
- Quit all instances of Terminal app and run it again
- Run sudo gem install ffi

After you finish the above several steps, restart your IDE and re-run the application.

Comment: I tried multiple possible things.... deleting pod and all but nothing worked for me.
Your single line command 'sudo gem install ffi' worked as charm. thanks:)

Comment: God among men. This worked.